# Counterexample for algorithim to find duplicates in an Array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Thank you for taking your time to answer a really simple question. I had a coding challenge recently and after optimizing, I made an algorithm that I am sure does not work but could not find a test case that breaks it. Can someone much more experienced than me give me a test case that does not work? And can you also verify that the algorithm is O(n) time and O(1) space complexity? Here is the problem.

**Challenge:**

Write an algorithm that returns a duplicate integer from an array of integers. This array is constructed such that every integer is greater than 1(inclusive) and less than the length of the array(exclusive).

**Input:**

An array of integers of size N, where every integer, x, follows the rule, 1 <= x < N

**Output:**

An integer that is duplicated in the input.

**Examples:**

Input: [1, 2, 3, 1] 
output: 1

Input: [2, 3, 4, 2, 4]
output: 2 or 4

**Algorithm that should not work:**

```py
def find_duplicates(arr):
    curr_n = arr[0]
    while True:
        removed_n = arr[curr_n]
        if removed_n == curr_n:
            return curr_n
        arr[curr_n] = curr_n
        curr_n = removed_n
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a counterexample? I tried randomly generating a million test inputs, and I couldn't find any that didn't give the correct answer.

Comment: What specific test case failed it? The code seems to work, although it is a bit confusing (why not use set?)

Comment: @NickODell I am actually not sure. We spent one or two minutes during the interview trying to come up with a counter test. I could not find one at all, so I'm thinking there might be some flaw in my logic, which seems to be not the case...

Comment: @EricJin I used a dict at first, but the interviewers wanted a lower space complexity while keeping an O(n) time complexity. So we ended hacking this code together.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(n).

Each iteration, it sets `arr[i] = i` for some index i, or stops if `arr[i] == i` already.  There are only O(n) indexes that it can fix, so it takes O(n) time.

You algorithm also *works*.  In fact it's quite good.

If we consider a number to be "in the right place" when `arr[i] == i`, then at the beginning of each iteration of the loop, we know that we got `curr_n` from a *wrong* place.  We know this for the first iteration, because there is no 0 in the array, so `arr[0]` is always in the wrong place.  We know this for subsequent iterations because we check that with `if removed_n == curr_n`.

So we know that `curr_n` comes from a wrong place.  If we also find the same number in the *right* place, then it's a duplicate and we return it.

If you just change the variable names, how it works becomes a lot clearer:

```
def find_duplicate(arr):
    misplaced = arr[0]
    while True:
        replacing = arr[misplaced]
        if replacing == misplaced:
            return misplaced
        arr[misplaced] = misplaced
        misplaced = replacing
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This really, really, really assured me that my logic was sound and that I did not perform some critical error in logic.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle Detection approach

```
def duplicate(arr):
    slow = arr[arr[0]]
    fast = arr[arr[arr[0]]]
    while slow != fast:
        slow = arr[slow]
        fast = arr[arr[fast]]
    fast = arr[0]
    while slow != fast:
        slow = arr[slow]
        fast = arr[fast]
    return slow
```